# Delete mails directly without moving to Trash in Evolution

Tags: 16.04, evolution

How to delete mails without moving to Trash in Evolution? Holding Ctrl and delete like in other apps doesn't work for me.

- Evolution 3.18.5.2
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Temporarily without Evolution so I cannot check. Holding Shift and delete, pop up box, to confirm permanent deletion. Please try on your computer and answer here if it works on 17:10. I suffered motherboard failure, so I am building up a machine and will be installing 17:10 with Evolution.

Comment: The manual of evolution does not mention this function so I unfortunately don't think this is working. However it says [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-delete-and-undelete.html.) that messages are normally not deleted but just marked as deleted. To free the space you have to go to `Folder → Clean`. But if you are really into the subject you can consider to contact the members of the evolution project so that they can improve their functions.